# Probability of an event when 3 coins are tossed and the probability of heads is 1/3?

Tags: probability

I know the sample space is

```
S = {HHH, HHT, HTH, HTT, THH, THT, TTH, TTT}
```

If the P(H) = 1/2 then each sample point would have a 1/8 probability of occurring but what if P(H) = 1/3? How would I go about solving a problem like this?

For example. If I wanted to find the probability that the second toss would be heads (A) I'd have the the following sample points:

```
A = {HHH, HHT, THH, THT}
```

If P(H) = 1/2 then the probability that the second toss would be heads would be `1/8 + 1/8 + 1/8 + 1/8 = 4/8 = 1/2`

If it was P(H) = 1/3 how would this change the calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if $P(H) = \frac{1}{3}$, then $$P(HHH)=\frac{1}{27}$$, $$P(THH) = P(HHT)=\frac{2}{27},$$ $$P(THT) = \frac{4}{27}.$$

Then $P(A) = \frac{9}{27} = \frac{1}{3}$.

EDIT: as @Éric Guirbal's comment.
Note that $P(T) = 1 - P(H)$ and $P(HT) = P(H)P(T)$ with the assumption that the coin tosses are independent.

Comment: Maybe we should add that $P(T) = 1 - P(H)$, and $P(HTH) = P(H)\times P(T)\times P(H)$ because the coin tosses are supposed to be independent.

Comment: Yep, my mistake. Edited.

Comment: Ah okay. So to find the probability of each sample point I need to multiply the probabilities of getting head or tails. So for P(HHT) = 1/3 * 1/3 * 2/3 = 2/27. Makes sense.